# BIG/SPAN (RAID): How does it works here?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I have some questions about [BIG/SPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-RAID_drive_architectures). In my question I will talk about two hard drives spanned together.

- How is the data spanned across the two drives? Will it span according to files or on byte level? Or does this depend on the controller?
- Can you access the data of the hard drive which didn't failed without the origin controller? Is it possible to access the data of only one hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIG/SPAN suffers all the same drawbacks as JBOD, except it presents as a partition (volume) rather then a drive.

So-
It works”on a byte” level” would be closer then file - actually it works on a block level.

It does not let you access remaining data if the first drive fails
 You MIGHT have limited luck if other drives fail - for recovery purposes depending on the filesystem, fragmentation etc.

You cant rely on it working in the absence of the controller, but, I imagine it will work with a similar controller if you get lucky.

SPAN/BIG plays as fast and loose with your data as JBOD.

Comment: Depends on implementation.  ZFS and btrfs can span multiple devices and store files redundantly, too, like 2× 500 GB drives and 1× 1 TB drive with everything doubled